# Remover ciertos datos de dos tablas al seleccionar solo fila una de las jtable

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

[image: <code>introducir el código aquí</code>](Con 2 jTable)Alguien ya ha podido remover datos de dos tablas al mismo tiempo al seleccionar solo una fila de una tabla. Obteniendo "jtabla.getValueAt(row,id)" de una las tablas como un tipo de condición que recorra todo y si existe se remueva todo lo que cumpla con la CONDICIÓN! ; sera posible hacerlo? Lo he estado probando y solo logro eliminar lo que seleccionó y luego errores de -1 Array. Entre otros no captura nada. Esto es sin Sql, solo para poder quitar un detalle(tabla2) con su producto(tabla1)

```java
 int fila = tablaAgregar.getSelectedRow();
        int fila2 = tablaAgregarDeposito.getSelectedRow();

        int dato_tablaAgregar;
//        int cd = 0;
        dato_tablaAgregar = Integer.parseInt(tablaAgregar.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());//este es el valor que deseo quitar
        //de la siguiente tabla

        //  if(cp == cp){
        for (int j = 0; j < tablaAgregarDeposito.getRowCount(); j++) {
            int rowModelId = tablaAgregar.convertRowIndexToModel(j);
            if (tablaAgregarDeposito.getValueAt(rowModelId, 1).equals(dato_tablaAgregar)) {
                tablaAgregarDeposito.scrollRectToVisible(tablaAgregarDeposito.getCellRect(j, 1,true));
                tablaAgregarDeposito.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(j, j);
//                tablaAgregarDeposito.changeSelection(j, 1, false, false); //esto n

                modeloAgregarDepo.removeRow(fila2);//remueve
                break;

            }
            //  }
        }
//      Luego quita el dato de la tabla que use como la consulta (dato_tablaAgregar)
        ////////
        if (fila >= 0) {
            modeloAgre.removeRow(fila);
            calcularTotal();
            txtCodigoProduc.requestFocus();
        } else {
            con.mensajes("Seleccione un registro");
        }
```

Comment: Si no adjuntas lo que has intentado poco podemos ayudarte...

Comment: Como te han dicho, sube el código que tengas para poder ayudarte, y de paso, reescribe la pregunta y la descripción porque es complicado entender lo que quieres hacer. ¿La primera frase es una pregunta o una afirmación?

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la sugerencia!! Ahí agregue una imagen y el codigo que se ejecuta al presionar Quitar. no logro hacer que funcione aun!